# I cant download Webex onto my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop

Tags: 20.04, webex

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my desktop. I tried to download Webex.deb onto my Ubuntu machine but I keep getting the message: "Failed to install file: not supported". I tried to install using Terminal commands: "sudo apt install ~/Downloads/Webex.deb" - message says "Not supported". I tried "sudo snap install snap-store" also.
Your Webex onLinux says it works for Ubuntu yet it does not work.

Comment: Have you looked at what type of file it is?  ie. `file ~/Downloads/Webex.deb` should show content like `Debian binary package (format 2.0), with control.tar.gz, data compression gz`  (ie. *the filename is not a reliable indication of what's inside the file; and it's what's inside that matters*)

Comment: *message says "Not supported"* -- Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Use `dpkg` for installing *.deb "Your Webex onLinux" -we- don't have a "Webex onLinux",

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) with correct deb-file from [link](https://binaries.webex.com/WebexDesktop-Ubuntu-Official-Package/Webex.deb) or maybe yours institution provides its mod .

Comment: All I know is what the webex site says it is, i.e. webex.deb. Full error message is exactly what I wrote above, i.e. "Failed to install file: not supported". dpkg is already installed.